# Using libphonenumber library in postgresql function

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sails.js, waterline, libphonenumber

I need to parse phone numbers in a postgresql function. I am using waterline ORM and was basically doing this computation in javascript. Now I want to move the entire logic to postgresql stored function. But the bottleneck is the availability of libphonenumber library. It's available in Node.js but not sure how to use it in postgresql.

Any idea ?

Comment: consider accepting my answer, though late to the game it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are C bindings available for [libphonenumber](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/164729/2639) already

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_libphonenumber;
SELECT parse_phone_number('03 7010 1234', 'AU') = parse_phone_number('(03) 7010 1234', 'AU');

CREATE TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT DISTINCT parse_phone_number(ph, 'AU')
  FROM ( VALUES
    ('0370101234'),
    ('03 7010 1234'),
    ('(03) 7010 1234')
  ) AS t(ph);
```

Find my answer [here for more information](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/164796/2639)

Answer (score 1):

Since it's available in C++ and JavaScript, you could:

- Install and load PL/V8 and use it as a JavaScript library in a PL/V8 stored procedure; or
- Write a C extension for PostgreSQL that exposes the functions as SQL-callable functions by wrapping the C++ functions in the C++ version of the library.

Needless to say, the former is probably easier, unless you're comfortable with C programming.